# Use ScriptEngine to bind global javascript functions from java code

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

```
public class JSBindings extends SimpleBindings{

    public void bind(String key, Object value){
        this.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I pass the instance of JSBindings to `ScriptEngine.eval(script, bindings)` in my code. However, I am only able to bind (put) java objects to SimpleBindings. How can I bind global javascript functions from java code?

i.e

```
bind("UTILS", new SomeJavaObject()) //works fine..
```

But I want to bind javascript functions. Perhaps something like this :

`bind("list", "function(){return new java.util.ArrayList()}")` `//doesn't work.. list is just a string`

so that when I say `list()` in my javascript, it must invoke this bind function and create an instance of ArrayList. Is it possible to bind javascript functions this way from an instance of SimpleBindings?

Comment: Why not just evaluate `list = function(){return new java.util.ArrayList()}`?